# How do I fix error building package on ppa, uses tweepy/quickly

Tags: python, ppa, quickly, launchpad, twitter

I'm building an application that uses tweepy (a python library) and when I build it on my local machine it works fine. When I submit it to launchpad though, it sent me a log which has this error: `ERROR: Python module tweepy not found`.

I found a ppa python-tweepy on Launchpad.

So how do I fix this error.

[The log from Launchpad is here.](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/109066317/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-i386.quicknote_12.07_FAILEDTOBUILD.txt.gz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the tweepy PPA as dependency for your PPA (you can do this from the Launchpad web interface for your PPA), and add python-tweepy as a build dependency in your package.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but I still get the same error... log is at https://launchpadlibrarian.net/109452102/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-i386.quicknote_12.07_FAILEDTOBUILD.txt.gz

Comment: Where is your source package? Is tweepy actually in the list of build dependencies?

Comment: You can try adding tweepy to the control file in your debian folder of your application, in the build dependencies section.

Comment: found my problem [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/07/ubuntu-app-showdown-deadline-approaching-get-your-submissions-ready/) (in troubleshooting section)